# change class attributes when hovering over other css class

Tags: class, css, html

I am trying to give a div with class "left2" a border-radius when class "left1_sub" is hovered.

I´ve searched a lot of solutions, but nothing seems to work for me.

The html to it: http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/ben/kleinraum/wp/menuimg/index.html
and the full css: http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/ben/kleinraum/wp/menuimg/style.css

```
.left1_sub{
     padding-top:2%;
     padding-bottom:2%;
     width: 100%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #cccccc
 }



.left1_sub:hover ~ .left2 {border-radius: 10px;}

.left2{

   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   width: 500px;
   height:600px;
   background-color: #ccccff
}
```

Just introducing myself to css3 so sorry if there are failures.

ben

Comment: Post your HTML *here*, in the *question*. Please don't expect people to go to your site and then view source in order to help you. Make it *easy* for *us* to help *you*. Also, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) demo (where we can see the code, and, *importantly*, *edit it* without having to download and create our *own* demos goes a long way to getting our help. Seriously. please: help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily with jQuery or something similar.

If are comfortable using jQuery something like this would work.

First, create a class in CSS with a border radius:

```
.rounded { border-radius: 5px; /* (or whatever) */ }
```

Then, in `<script>` tags:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var obj = $('.left1_sub'),
         target = $('.left2');

     obj.hover(
          //mouse in
         function(){
            target.addClass('rounded');
         //mouse out    
         },function(){
            target.removeClass('rounded');
     });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGzgB/11/

Comment: A note regarding why JavaScript was offered as a solution: CSS doesn't allow for the type of selecting the OP is asking for. CSS only traverses down the DOM (IE - siblings and children), not up it (IE - you can't select a parent element from a child). Since the OP's HTML would require going up out of the element that contains "left1_sub" to get to "left2", either JavaScript or an HTML restructure is necessary to achieve the OP's goal.

Comment: hey! thx, for the answer, will try for this special case. but still i am searching for a way to do it in pure css, since i want to use this method also on more complex stuff.

Comment: As @Shauna has said, this won't be possible with pure CSS without an HTML restructure

Comment: hey! just saw that there are other answers down here, sry, new to stack :) thx a lot, will try restructure.